# Simple bijection $\mathbb N_0 \times \mathbb N_0 \to \mathbb N_0$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory, soft-question

I'm looking for a 'simple' bijection
$$
\pi \colon \mathbb N_0 \times \mathbb N_0 \to \mathbb N_0,
$$

where 'simple' in this context means that it should be as easy as possible to define and it should be self-evident that said function is in fact a bijection. It's a quest for convenience - not minimal complexity in any rigorous sense.

Here are a couple of examples I came up with - none of which satisfy both requirements:

1. Let $\pi(m,n) = c(2^m3^{n+1})$, where $c \colon \{2^m3^{n+1} \mid m,n \in \mathbb N_0 \}\to \mathbb N_0$ is the order isomorphism (or in fact Mostowski collapse) of its domain under the natural ordering,
2. Let $\pi(m,n) = \langle n,m \rangle$ - Gödel's pairing function,
3. Let $\pi(m,n) = m \oplus n$ - the number resulting from '[riffling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuffling#Riffle)' $m,n$ (where we imagine both $m$ and $n$ as in infinite decks of cards whose $i$th element is labeled with its respective $i$th digit).
4. ...

Comment: You defined each one (or at least two of them) in only two lines. And I find it very self-evident that it is working. So what are you really looking for? A short *explicite arithmetic formula*? I am not sure how it could get *more easy/evident* than your examples.

Comment: @M.Winter I'm aware that this question isn't well defined and I'm not sure what exactly I'm looking for either. That's the reason I tagged it as a soft question. Basically I'm looking for an example I can easily present to any undergraduate whenever the need for some such bijection occurs.

Comment: I answered your question -https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/91318/proving-the-cantor-pairing-function-bijective/2479347#2479347 If simple means natural, you might like it. Of course what feels natural to me might look weird to you!

Comment: Just an apology - I went off the deep end with this question,  my responses do not appear to answer your question, I looked for another  math.stackexchange location, but this became my 'dumping' ground...

Comment: @MikeMathMan That's fine. I still think it may benefit other users who search through the site in the future. But, yes, I don't think that they answer my exact question which is the reason I didn't upvote them.

Comment: thanks for not down-voting them!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

$$\pi(n,m)=2^n(2m+1)-1$$

Break each natural number to a maximal even part, and an odd part. The $-1$ is there for getting $0$ into the fold.

Comment: This fits my bill perfectly. (I had thought about this exact function but its simple formulation skipped my mind.)

Comment: After seven years of teaching basic set theory, this is one thing I cannot forget. But yeah, it seemed evident from the way you phrased the "examples" that you were looking for this one. :P

Comment: I was about to say that! Came here too late, though... +1

Comment: Thats very beautiful!

Comment: @M.Winter: Thanks. I hate Cantor's pairing function. I could never understand the "drawing proof", and the inductive proofs are too complicated. I always use this one as a secondary and much better alternative when I teach students.

Comment: @Asaf - maybe you can now change the word 'hate' to 'dislike'! See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/91318/proving-the-cantor-pairing-function-bijective/2479347#2479347

Comment: Do you need the prime factorization theorem here?

Comment: @Mike: You need to know that every number has a largest multiple of $2$ which divides it, and the remainder is odd.

Answer (score 2):

The following (ugly, sorry) picture shows the desired map.

[image]

Comment: Your 'ugly' PAC-MAN picture inspired me!

Comment: I don't see how you *define* this bijection? Yeah, it's clear that this idea can be extended to a bijection. But now can you please write a formula which defines it? (Or alternatively, draw a picture over the whole infinite grid...) I want to know what is the pair $(n,m)$ which is mapped to $2^{100}-5^{36}$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Oh sure, that one is $$(658125460370987,1125893444475543)\mapsto 2^{100}-5^{36}$$

Comment: For all I know, these are two randomly generated numbers.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I understand what you are saying. I haven't had time to write out the explicit map for this, and will soon. It's true that finding that specific map wasn't particularly quick. I found the $n$ and that $n^2<2^{100}-5^{26}<(n+1)^2$ and then I classified when the next 'square' begins based on whether the 'square' is of even or odd side length, and then I counted backwards from the $(n+1)^2$ until I reached the correct node.

Comment: I'm not saying that I don't believe you that you did that. I'm just saying, there is no way for me to verify the correctness of your answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will fit, but it is an explicit arithmetic formula. It is called the Cantor [pairing function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function):

$$C(m,n)=\frac{(m+n)(m+n+1)}{2}+m$$

It is however not obvious that it works. But you can find a proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1364774/prove-that-cm-n-fracmnmn12m-is-a-bijection-from-mathbbn2?rq=1).

Comment: It can follow a natural progression - see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/91318/proving-the-cantor-pairing-function-bijective/2479347#2479347 for a proof.

Answer (score 1):

Asaf was interested in seeing an explicit formula for user469689's picture answer. It can be done following the algorithm described in theorem 1 on Cantor's Pairing Function (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2479347/432081)), but it would look messy with 'odd/even' cases since the picture describes a 'connected path'.  So we choose a slightly different path but one that highlights the same '[geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/671371/432081)':

$(0,0) \to$
$(1,0) \to (1,1) \to (0,1) \to $
$(2,0) \to (2,1) \to (2,2) \to (1,2) \to (0,2) \to $
$(3,0) \to (3,1) \to (3,2) \to (3,3) \to (2,3) \to (1,3) \to (0,3) \to $
$\text{etc.} \qquad \text{Figure 1}$

Here is the mapping:

$$   
    \pi(m,n) = \left\{\begin{array}{lr}
        n^2+2n-m, & \text{for } m \le n\\
        m^2+n, & \text{for } m \gt n
        \end{array}\right\} 
$$

As a check, apply $\pi$ to Figure 1:

$\pi(0,0) = 0$
$\pi(1,0)=1 \; \; \pi (1,1)=2 \; \; \pi (0,1)=3$
$\pi(2,0)=4 \; \; \pi (2,1)=5 \; \; \pi (2,2)=6 \; \; \pi (1,2)=7 \; \; \pi (0,2)=8 $
$\pi(3,0)=9 \; \; \pi (3,1)=10 \; \; \pi (3,2)=11 \; \; \pi (3,3)=12 \; \;  \pi (2,3) =13 \; \; \pi (1,3) =14 \; \; \pi (0,3)=15 $
$\text{etc.} \qquad \pi\text{(Figure 1)}$

Comment: Very nice (+1).

Answer (score 0):

WLOG, we are looking for a mapping $\pi \colon \mathbb N^* \times \mathbb N^* \to \mathbb N^*$, where $\mathbb N^*$ denotes the set of positive integers.

This idea is simple and has a geometric/visual appeal to it. You have an infinite grid, but when you look at the finite $n \times n$ initial square segments, you reason that that for starters, you always want to map coordinate pairs from the product diagonal as follows:

$\quad \pi(d,d) = d^2$

Now you have to 'back fill', so that $\pi$ maps these $d \times d$ squares bijectively onto the integer interval $[1,d^2]$.

Now intuitively, you might think that if you are 'close' to the main diagonal, you can start by squaring the larger coordinate and then finding a 'mild' adjustment. The adjustments get more 'heavy handed' as you move away from the diagonal.

Here is the mapping:

$$   
    \pi(m,n) = \left\{\begin{array}{lr}
        m^2-2(m-n) , & \text{for } m \ge n\\
        n^2-2(n-m)+ 1, & \text{for } m \lt n
        \end{array}\right\} 
$$

So,
$\quad \pi(5,3) = 25 - 4 = 21$
$\quad \pi(1,6) = 36 - 10 + 1 = 27$

I used google sheets to verify; here is the visual:

[image]

Using induction on the $n \times n$ squares, you can wrap this up.

Exercise: Show that $\pi$ is bijective.

Note: The google sheet/image is off in the $(m,n) = (5,4)$ cell; the correct entry is $\pi(5,4) = 23$.

Comment: How is this self evidently injective, or surjective, or **simple to define**? It's like you don't even read the actual questions...

Comment: I thought the visuals drove the whole process. If I am stranded on a deserted island and trying to remember this, I might just mumble to myself $6^2 = 36$ and the rest follows. I wouldn't think about pulling out a $2^n$ factor. So again, we are different people. .

Comment: Huh? I don't see what your reply has to do with my comment. Also, if you are stranded on a lonely island, why do you need to remember how to match the line and the grid?

Comment: It is possible my days would take care of themselves and I would not have time for thinking about math stuff. But my memory is not great, and my thinking usually begins on blank page.

Comment: I solved this intuitively on paper 'knowing' I had a bijection,, firmed it up in a google sheet, and then saw an easy inductive proof (see exercise).

Answer (score 0):

I want to give one final answer here. It uses the same [$1+2+3+\dots+n$]-math as the Cantor Pairing Function, and also the fact that there is a modulo-3 partition on the integers.

Set

$\qquad  \mu (m,n) =  \frac{(m-1)(m)}{2} + n + 1$

The mapping $\pi: \mathbb N \times \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ is defined by

$$   
    \pi(m,n) = \left\{\begin{array}{lr}
        3 \, \mu(m,n) - 2, & \text{for } m \gt n\\
        3m, & \text{for } m = n\\
        3 \, \mu(n,m) - 1,, & \text{for } m \lt n
        \end{array}\right\} 
$$

It is easy to show that the function $\pi$ takes the $m \gt n$ ordered pairs  bijectively onto $3 {\mathbb N}^{*} -2$.  Once you prove that, a $\text{symmetry & translation}$ argument shows that $\pi$ takes the $n \gt m$ ordered pairs bijectively onto  $3 \, {\mathbb N}^{*} - 1$. The only thing left is  $3 {\mathbb N}$, and that is what the dividing line, the diagonal $m = n$, is used for.

---

This is a 'hack approach' and might have been found before the Cantor Pairing Function was discover in $1878$. In any case, Cantor must have been amazed with his discovery. Several of the other answers shown here split up the domain for the formula definition - they can't outdo Cantor's closed formula.

If you want to find simple solutions, you are hereby warned not to look at the [Fueter–Pólya theorem/conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fueter%E2%80%93P%C3%B3lya_theorem) wikipedia article.